# Java: Using array as parameters conditions for inserting data to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, logging

```
package com.example.dev1.controller;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
/*import java.sql.ResultSet;*/
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class ReadLg extends JApplet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        String[] lev_param = { "DEBUG", "WARN", "INFO", "ERROR" };
        List<String> listparam = Arrays.asList(lev_param);
        String temp = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        Connection con = null;
        /* ResultSet rs = null; */

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("All.log"));
            String username = ****;
            String pwd = ****;
            String connurl = "jdbc:mysql://10.247.36.174:3306/d_accesslog?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connurl, username, pwd);

            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                temp+=line;
                if (line.equals(listparam)) {
                    String sql = "INSERT INTO t_weblogic_test (RawData) values ('\''+line+'\'')";
                    temp=null;
                } 

                ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.executeUpdate();
            }

            br.close();
            con.close();
            ps.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So, I've got a little confused on how to insert the array as parameter condition.
I want to add array as my parameter.  in this program, I read log data and set log level as my parameter condition, so when it read the next log level it will stop and insert the data to the DB. therefore I've got a bit confused on how the exact way to do this.

this log file will seems like below 
"DEBUG [CorporateUserSMImpl] 30-05-2019 00:01:04: id = 2c9dc30c673209d201675e3e5c961456"
"WARN [LoginAction] 30-05-2019 00:01:04: Login process for go MAIN page batchID = 2c9dc30c6ac6b815016b0452cd3d41ef time ENDCALLBO= 2019-05-30 00:01:04.198"

so when it read the next log level it will stop and save previous line

NEW!!! 
what if the log file seems like below
"DEBUG [AccountDAOImpl] 30-05-2019 00:01:45: .....

start calling method getByAccountGroupIdAndIsInquiryPicklistWithAccountTypeNew 12
"DEBUG [AccountDAOImpl] 30-05-2019 00:01:45: currentPage =1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to optimize here. Your specific problem is that you compare your whole line against your ArrayList which will not work: `line.equals(listparam)`. You should take the first token of your line and see if your list contains such a value. One possible way to do this would be:

```
String firstWord = line.split(" ",2)[0];
if(listparam.contains(firstWord)) {

}
```

Next I would recommend using a try-with-resources construction to create your `con`, `ps` and `br` resources. This will automatically close them if anything goes wrong. Also, i would create the PreparedStatement with a prepared parameter to pass the log message eventually, instead of just concatenate it in the sql string. This will be better for performance as you'll only need to create the statement once, and it's safer.

I have rewritten your code a bit below, this is untested so might still contain some flaws, but I hope you get the general idea:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String connurl = "jdbc:mysql://10.247.36.174:3306/d_accesslog?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
    String username = "****";
    String pwd = "****";
    // Use a prepared parameter in the sql string
    String sql = "INSERT INTO t_weblogic_test (RawData) values (?)";

    String[] levParam = { "DEBUG", "WARN", "INFO", "ERROR" };
    List<String> listparam = Arrays.asList(levParam);

    // Use a try-with-resources block to automatically handle the closing of the resources
    try(Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connurl, username, pwd); 
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("All.log"));) {

      String line = null;
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // Get first token
        String firstWord = line.split(" ",2)[0];
        if(listparam.contains(firstWord)) { // Start of the first log message
          // Process all the messages from the log file
          processMessages(line, br, listparam, ps);
          break;
        }
      }
    } catch(SQLException ex) {
      // ex handling
    } catch(IOException ex) {
      // ex handling
    }
  }

  private static void processMessages(String line, BufferedReader br, List<String> listparam, PreparedStatement ps) throws IOException, SQLException {
    String message = line;

    // Scan until the end of the message, eg the start of the next message
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      // Get first token
      String firstWord = line.split(" ",2)[0];
      if(listparam.contains(firstWord)) { // Start of the next log message
        // Insert your message
        ps.setString(1, message);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        message = line; // Start of the new message
      } else { // Continuation of the current message
        message = message.concat(line);
      }
    }

    if(!message.isEmpty()) {
      // Insert the last message from the log file
      ps.setString(1, message);
      ps.executeUpdate();
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you for ur response. I'm a little bit confused on how the SQL works. you change the value into (?). so in which session it will insert the value from a string to db?

Comment: Question marks used in the sql are parameter placeholders. The `ps.setString(1, message)` will ensure the driver replaces the parameter with the message as a string. The '1' indicates you want to replace the first parameter. That way you can use multiple parameters in a sql string and use the `ps.setString()`, `ps.setInt()`, ... methods to set the values for those parameters. This system ensures the statement only needs to be compiled once, as only the parameter values change and not the whole sql string. It also prevents sql injection, as the driver handles the replacement of the parameters.

Comment: I hope this makes it a bit clear, but also have a look at [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for additional info.

Comment: thank you.. and I want to ask the last question if u don't mind
line.split(" ",2)[0].. how to read this line?

Comment: This will split the line based on the " " delimiter, so after each space, and stores the result in an array. The '2' indicates the size of the resulting array, since we only need the first word in this case, 2 is sufficient. Index 0 of the resulting array will then contain our first word, index 1 of the array will contain the rest of the line. If you omit the limit parameter ('2'), the resulting array will contain an entry for each separate word.

Comment: hmm.. i just realized that it just work if the format is
"debug blablabla blabla"
"warn blablabla"
and not work if
"debug blablabla"
"bla bla bla bla"
"warn blablabla"

so what the main point of adding parameters is for reading until it found the next param. if found then the string from previous will be saved

Comment: im just added a new example above can u help me if the example is like the new above?

Comment: It should work in those cases as well. With the new example you gave in your original post, you should get 2 DEBUG entries in the database, the first one concatenating the 3 lines from the first debug message, the second one containing the second debug message. It will strip the newlines from the messages though. So unless I'm not completely getting what you really expect as a result, I think the solution should work fine.

Comment: but when i run the program u've made it never go to first if on the main...
if the log level on my log file has '<' at the first and '>' at the end of the log level.. does this will affect the .contains? i mean in my log file the log level write like this <debug>

Comment: and when I remove "<>" from log level in my log file it runs perfectly.. so if I want the program to read "<debug>" should i change the parameter? or i change the code?

Comment: Yes, your `levParam` list only contains the tokens `"DEBUG", "WARN", "INFO" and "ERROR"`, and they need to exactly match the first word of your log lines. If your log contains "<DEBUG>", you `levParam` list should also include "<DEBUG>": `String[] levParam = { "DEBUG", "WARN", "INFO", "ERROR", "<DEBUG>", "<WARN>", "<INFO>", "<ERROR>" };`. If you would put a breakpoint on the if statement and debug your program you would easily be able to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert array as parameters conditions for inserting data to MySQL by replacing sql as mentioned below :

String[] levParam = { "DEBUG", "WARN", "INFO", "ERROR" };
    List listparam = Arrays.asList(levParam);

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     String line=null;

            String firstWord= line.split(" \\[")[0];
            if(listparam.contains(firstWord)) { 

      processMessages(line, br, listparam, ps);

    }
}


   private static void processMessages(String line, BufferedReader br, List<String> listparam, PreparedStatement ps) throws IOException, SQLException {
String message = line;

// Scan until the end of the message, eg the start of the next message
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

 String lastWord= s.split(" \\[")[1];

    // Insert your message
     String sql = "INSERT INTO t_weblogic_test (RawData) values ('\''+lastWord+'\'')";
       ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
       ps.executeUpdate();
    message = line; // Start of the new message

}
```

Comment: thank you but, this isn't what I mean. what I mean is how to make array as parameters. My array param is my log level which contains { "DEBUG", "WARN", "INFO", "ERROR" }. so when I read the log file it will read each line and will stop when reading log level and save the previous line

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.dev1.controller;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ReadLg3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String conn = "jdbc:mysql://ipaddress/d_accesslog?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
        String username = "****";
        String pwd = "****";
        String sql = "INSERT INTO t_weblogic_test (RawData) values (?)";

        String[] levParam = { "<DEBUG>", "<WARN", "<INFO", "<ERROR>","INFO", "WARN","DEBUG","ERROR" };
        List<String> listparam = Arrays.asList(levParam);

        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(conn, username, pwd);
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("All.log"));) {

            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String firstWord = line.split(" ", 2)[0];
                if (listparam.contains(firstWord)) {
                    processMessages(line, br, listparam, ps);
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.err.println("Failed!!");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Error in \n" + ex);
        }
    }

    public static void processMessages(String line, BufferedReader br, List<String> listparam, PreparedStatement ps)
            throws Exception {
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
        message.append(line);
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String firstWord = line.split(" ", 2)[0];
            if (listparam.contains(firstWord)) {
                ps.setString(1, message.toString());
                ps.executeUpdate();
                message.setLength(0);
                message.append(line);
            } else {
                message.append("\n" + line);
            }
        }

        if (message.length() > 0) {
            ps.setString(1, message.toString());
            ps.executeUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

For more performance use string builder